# Ignoring specific remotes when running `magit-log-popup` to log all branches

Tags: magit

I would like to add an option in `magit-log-popup` to ignore a list of remotes  when using "Log all branches" (`l b`). What I'm trying to do is something like this `git log HEAD --branches --remotes --not --remotes=remote1 --remotes=remote2`. All my attempts to add this have failed and I wondered if anybody have a suggestion on how it could be done?

Tried variations of things like this `(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-log-popup ?i "Ignore remotes" "--not --remotes=" #'read-from-minibuffer)`. Though I might expanded it later with a function, but it caused the log come up empty.

Comment: A better solution would be to make local branches of what should be tracked and use `b L` ("Log local branches").

Answer (score 0):

> Tried variations of things like this `(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-log-popup ?i "Ignore remotes" "--not --remotes=" #'read-from-minibuffer)`. Though I might expanded it later with a function, but it caused the log come up empty.

This does not work because when you define `"--not --remotes="` as a single argument, then it is—unsurprisingly—passed to Git as a single argument `--not --remotes=VALUE`. Git then errors out because it has no such argument.

You should be able to achieve what you want by adding two separate arguments `--not` and `--remote=` to the popup. You will have to make sure that they appear in the correct order in the popup and you will have to enable both separately.